# How do you run Xilinx91i in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, xilinx

I installed Xilinx91i on my comp under /usr/Xilinx91i/, but I don't know how to start it. Can someone help?

Comment: What, is there no documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found it. Is it under /usr/Xilinx91i/bin/lin/ise?

correct me if i'm wrong